# How to create a health check endpoint for RabbitQM in Nestjs

Tags: rabbitmq, health-check, nestjs-microservice

This is my health check code for RabbitMQ.

```
import {
    Controller,
    Get
} from '@nestjs/common';
import {
    RmqOptions,
    Transport
} from '@nestjs/microservices';
import {
    HealthCheck,
    HealthCheckService,
    HttpHealthIndicator,
    MicroserviceHealthIndicator,
} from '@nestjs/terminus';

@Controller('health-check')
export class HealthCheckController {
    constructor(
        private healthCheckService: HealthCheckService,
        private http: HttpHealthIndicator,
        private microservice: MicroserviceHealthIndicator,
    ) {}

    @Get()
    @HealthCheck()
    check() {
        return this.healthCheckService.check([
            () => this.http.pingCheck('nestjs-docs', 'https://docs.nestjs.com'),
            () =>
            this.microservice.pingCheck < RmqOptions > ('rabbitmq', {
                transport: Transport.RMQ,
                options: {
                    urls: [process.env.AMQP_URL],
                    queue: 'user_queue',
                    queueOptions: {
                        durable: false,
                    },
                },
            }),
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I hit endpoint to check health I face following error.
`
{
"status": "error",
"info": {

```
},
"error": {
    "nestjs-docs": {
        "status": "down",
        "message": "unexpected end of file"
    },
    "rabbitmq": {
        "status": "down",
        "message": "timeout of 1000ms exceeded"
    }
},
"details": {
    "nestjs-docs": {
        "status": "down",
        "message": "unexpected end of file"
    },
    "rabbitmq": {
        "status": "down",
        "message": "timeout of 1000ms exceeded"
    }
}
```

}
`

What is this error and how can I solve this error

I tried to check health but I face above mention error. I saw the documentation of Nestjs and Nestjs github examples but there is redis health check code but not rabbitmq code. I converted redis health check code to rabbitmq. But I failed to get result.